# Codeigniter model error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I created a new model class as `my_model.php` inside `/models` folder, and a function inside it to load all elements:

```
function get_all(){
    $query = $this->db->get('test'); //test is my table 
   return $query->result();
}
```

In the controller, I instantiated the class and called the method;

```
$this->load->model('my_model');
$res = $this->my_model->get_all();
```

But, this throws me error saying:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /var/www/testapp/application/models/my_model.php on line 7

This line 7 points to the portion of the code where I have used `$this->db`. I tried to see the value of `$db` but I think it is magic accessor `__get` and `__set`, so I could not see the value of this property before calling that method.

I tried googling for several other cases but none of them match my scenarios and rather none of them could solve my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to load the Database first

```
$this->load->database();
```

So, all code:

```
function get_all(){
    $this->load->database();
    $query = $this->db->get('test'); //test is my table 
    return $query->result();
}
```

**Or**, load database in your `__construct` method.

**Or**, IMO, It's better to autoload database by changing `application/config/autoload.php`, example is below.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','form_validation'); //form_validation is for example only
```

Comment: If this was the case, the error would have been something like `"undefined property 'db'..."` or failure to load the model.

Comment: @Madmartigan I don't think so, PHP interpreter will exit after not finding `get`, because it's a Fatal Error, will not provide a `Notice` (if `db` is a an undefined property or not).

Comment: I tried locally to trigger the error but couldn't figure out how to *not* have the database loaded... but this was in a bloated CMS so there was a lot of stuff cross-loading, I couldn't figure it out. I assumed CI would be able to catch this and use `show_error()`...

Comment: Ah I see, the error could be due to declaring `$db` in the Model. Then `db` *would* be defined, just not an object.

Answer (score 3):

In CodeIgniter, you should load database model before you use it.
Use `$this->load->database();` to load database model.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is actually quite simple:

```
return $query->result;
```

Should be:

```
return $query->result();
```

Sometimes the line number reported by a PHP error isn't exactly the one you think it is, the parser is just doing it's best and reporting where it found an error.

There's one more issue:

```
$res = $this->my_model->getAll();
```

Should be:

```
$res = $this->my_model->get_all();
```

You have called your own function by the wrong name.

Comment: I think the error is in this `$query = $this->db->get('test');`.

Comment: @insane-36: If you are posting in a hurry, maybe you are coding in a hurry too. Try to slow down a bit and pay attention. Can we see the entire model class and controller method code?

Comment: No harm done, glad you got it working. Just use the `autoload.php` - no need to manually load the database class in each model.

Comment: Hmm, the autoload should have worked. I'm not too sure, maybe there's another issue. Like I said in the comment on Usman's answer, I'm testing and can't figure out how to get the db class to *not* load :/